# Quaternions question

Tags: quaternions

Got a question about Quaternions.

I can kind of get that for $q=a+b{\bf i}+c{\bf j}+d{\bf k}$, $\bf i,j,k$ are square roots of -1, what I don't get is why ${\bf ijk} = -1$ ?

Any enlightenments? :)

Comment: It is by definition. Without that relation you don't get the quaternions. Also, the relation $ijk=-1$ cannot be deduced from the other equations and ring axioms.

Comment: If you want you can set $ijk =$ something else and see what happens, but then you won't get the quaternions

Comment: See [this thread from a week ago for essentially the same discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2400940/11619)

Comment: In complex numbers, it's very unhelpful (and very common) to think that $i = \sqrt{-1}$. Actually, $\sqrt{-1} = \pm i$. I think the same issue comes to bite you here. The safe way to think about them is $i^2 (= j^2 = k^2) = 1$, but otherwise make no connection between $i$ and the real numbers.

Comment: Sorry for duplicate. Thanks for answer.