# Does $i^2* j^2 = (i*j)^2$ in $\mathbb H$ ? (Proving $ij = k$ from $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$)

Tags: quaternions

I was trying to prove $ij = k$ from $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$
by doing:

(1) $i^2 = j^2$

(2) $\Rightarrow i^2 j^2 = 1$ (multiplying both sides with $j^2$ ($j^4 = 1$))

(3) $\Rightarrow i^2 j^2 = k^4$

(4) $\Rightarrow (ij)^2 = k^4$

(5) $\Rightarrow ij = k^2$

Obviously this is not right, especially because
there is no way I could have proven it without assuming ijk=-1 according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400940/how-do-i-prove-that-ij-k)

Still though, I'd like to know where my mistake is, I assume it's between (3) and (4) but why does $x^{u}y^{u} = (xy)^{u}$ not hold in $\mathbb H$ ?

Comment: The short answer is that multiplication is not commutative in $\Bbb{H}$ so $ijij \neq iijj$

Comment: What Jim H said. Another mistake is between steps (4) and (5). From $a^2=b^2$ you cannot conclude that $a=b$. This fails even in real numbers: $(-1)^2=1^2$ yet $-1\neq1$.

Comment: This would also prove that $ij=j$ since $i^2j^2=j^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistakes are (4) and (5).

(4) because $x^ny^n=(xy)^n$ if $x$ and $y$ commute. If they don't commute, it may not hold as in your example. Indeed, $i^2j^2=1$ but $(ij)^2=k^2=-1$.

(5) because even in a more familiar structure like $\mathbb{R}$, you have $(-4)^2=2^4$ but $-4\neq 2^2$.